# How to move a rectangle using motion event?

Tags: android

Is it possible to move a rectangle using motion event? I can only move it using circle, when I used rect it doesn't

```
public  boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event) 
{
    int eventaction = event.getAction();
    int X =(int)event.getX();
    int Y =(int)event.getY();

    switch (eventaction){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            rectx = X;
            recty = Y;
            invalidate();// call invalidate to refresh the draw
        break;
    }

    return true;
}
```